# Dijit events not working in dynamic panes

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

Can someone tell me why none of the [following](http://www.client-ms.com/test3/) will work?

**EDIT**
*(Just incase the link goes down this question is about how you can't seem to fire events in a page that is loaded into a dijit pane. This is applicable for Firefox 6.0.2, Crome 12.0.742.100 and Opera 11.00.1156 )*

```
<!-- index.html -->


<script>
    dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
        dijit.byId("mainSettings").set("href","index2.html");
    });
</script>

<body class="claro">
    <div id="main" dojoType="dijit.layout.BorderContainer">
        <div dojoType="dojox.layout.ContentPane" splitter="false" id="mainSettings" region="center"></div>
    </div>
</body>


<!-- index2.html -->


<!-- THIS WORKS!!! -->

<select dojoType="dijit.form.Select">
    <option value="bool">On/Off</option>
    <option value="date">Date</option>
    <option value="float">Number</option>
    <option value="text">Text</option>
    <script type="dojo/method" event="onChange">
        alert("change");
    </script>
</select>

<!-- NONE OF THIS WORKS!!! -->

<select dojoType="dijit.form.Select" onChange="change1">
    <option value="bool">On/Off</option>
    <option value="date">Date</option>
    <option value="float">Number</option>
    <option value="text">Text</option>
</select>
<script type="dojo/method" event="change1">
    alert("change1");
</script>



<button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" onClick="change2">
    change2
</button>
<script type="dojo/method" event="change2">
    alert("change2");
</script>


<script>
    dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
        dojo.connect(dijit.byId('button2'), 'onClick', function(){
            alert("change3");
        });
    });
</script>
<button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" id="button2">
    button2
</button>
```

**EDIT**
Dojango code:

```
#forms.py

type = CharField(widget=Select(choices=VARIABLE_CHOICES,attrs={'onChange':'letterVariableTypeSelectChange'}))

#template

{{ form.type }}
<script>
    function letterVariableTypeSelectChange(){
        alert("dave");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can people that down vote this post please give reasons

Comment: My guess is you were downvoted because StackOverflow is not a _crowdsource debugger_. A post that simply says "why does this not work" does not show much effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `executeScripts` and `parseOnLoad` properties to true on the dojox.layout.ContentPane

```
<div id="main" dojoType="dijit.layout.BorderContainer">
        <div dojoType="dojox.layout.ContentPane" executeScripts="true" parseOnLoad="true" splitter="false" id="mainSettings" region="center"></div>
</div>
```

There also appears to be a fundamental disparity to how you are using dojo/method.

The `<script type="dojo/method">` tags should go inside the elements that they are overriding

Notice how your snippet that works is defined:

```
<select dojoType="dijit.form.Select">
    <option value="bool">On/Off</option>
    <option value="date">Date</option>
    <option value="float">Number</option>
    <option value="text">Text</option>
    <!--Script tag inside widget node, event is the name of the event to override -->
    <script type="dojo/method" event="onChange">
        alert("change");
    </script>
</select>
```

versus the ones that don't work:

```
<!--onChange here is specified directly on the widget (which is incorrect), should be in the 
    <script type="dojo/method" event="OnChange"> 
-->
<select dojoType="dijit.form.Select" onChange="change1">
    <option value="bool">On/Off</option>
    <option value="date">Date</option>
    <option value="float">Number</option>
    <option value="text">Text</option>
</select>
<!--script tag outside the select.  event refers to a nonexistent event for the widget.-->
<script type="dojo/method" event="change1">
    alert("change1");
</script>
```

You get can the list of available events that you can use dojo/method to override at the reference documentation for a given widget.

http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dijit/form/FilteringSelect

Comment: thanks for the `executeScripts="true" parseOnLoad="true"` I was unaware of this, I have attached the code to the `dojox.layout.ContentPane` on the page with no avail :( The reason I'm wondering if you can place `<script type="dojo/method" event="change1">` outside of the input field is because I'm using dojango and I can't put them inside (django declaires the widget for you, and if you declare it yourself django won't populate it)

Comment: can you update your question with the relevant dojango code that creates the select's you are having problems with?

Comment: I cut and paste the dojango code but I fear my problem is more systemic. If I cut and past the html dojango produces into a simple page it works. If I cut and past the html produced into a simple page with `<div dojoType="dijit.form.Form" ...` it works as well. So I'm not to sure where the error comes from

Comment: the error is `letterVariableTypeSelectChange is not defined`. The code produced is: `<select name="type" onChange="aaa" dojoType="dijit.form.Select">
<option value="bool">On/Off</option>
<option value="date">Date</option>
<option value="float">Number</option>
<option value="text">Text</option>
</select>
<script>
    function aaa(){
        alert("dave");
    }
</script>`

Comment: It turns out that the error was because that one of my many nested `ContentPane`s was a `dijit.layout.ContentPane` not a `dojox.layout.ContentPane`. This might answer my dojango problem but I am none the wiser why some events trigger in a static page and not in a dynamic page